# System does not boot anymore after dpkg repair packages

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I succeeded to dual-boot Ubuntu over my Windows on my Alienware 14 (GTX 765M, i7, 8Go RAM).

However,I did something wrong when trying to fix the packages using the dpkg repair (When booting in the recovery menu, by launching "dpkg Repair broken packages").
Now, when I boot selecting Ubuntu from the boot menu, I simply obtain a purple screen, without loading, and it is never ending (it seems to be actually).

Do you have any idea to fix this problem ? Is it necessary to use my mounted USB in order to fix this ?

EDIT:
I successfully launched Ubuntu from the recovery menu by selecting a previous kernel version. However,  my Ubuntu just failed while trying to access settings and I was unable to even download a package as my dpkg is not configured anymore.

I found something very weird, that I show you on the below screen (I could not take a screenshot I am sorry for that)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Hi you could try "Ctr + Alt + F1". This could/should give you a command line. 
From there you could do "sudo apt-get update" and "sudo apt-get upgrade"  or 
whatever is necessary.

Comment: Where do I need to type this ? When I have the purple screen it is completely frozen and it does nothing. I tried when booting in recovery mode and it does not change anything.